# how to create a function like something.function() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have this function:

```
function test(firstNumber,SecondNumber){
  return (firstNumber*secondNumber);
}
```

I want to do the same function (the above function) in a different way like bellow and I want to know how is it possible in JavaScript:

```
var firstNumber= 10; //some number;
firstNumber.test(secondNumber);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a custom prototype of [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for it.

```js
Number.prototype.test = function (n) {
    return this * n;
}

var firstNumber = 10; //some number;
document.write(firstNumber.test(15));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the `Number` object with your own functions.

```
Number.prototype.test = function (other) {
    return this.valueOf() * other;
};

var firstNumber = 10;
var secondNumber = 10;

firstNumber.test(secondNumber);
```

Please keep in mind that extending native Javascript objects is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242/2190953).

Answer (score 1):

Just some other way instead of extending native javascript objects

```
var utils = {
  add: function(a, b) {
   return (a + b)
  }
}

var one = 1
var two = 2

utils.add(1, 2) // prints 3
```